# How to delete all occurrences of an item in a list?

Tags: ocaml

So...I have a few problems with that,my goal is to delete items from a list as follows.

For example,I have a list like that:

`let list = [1;2;4;5;1;1;6]`

And when i do some like this:

`remove_from_list 1 list`

I want this list back (delete all 1):

`[2;4;5;6]`

Therefore, I would have a type: 'a ->' a list -> 'a list function,if I'm not mistaken...How can I do this with **List.filter** from Module List? (I've managed to do it without applying .filter but I can't do it this way)

Comment: What specifically have you tried?

Comment: @glennsl This is what I have done: `let rec remove_from_list n =function
  []->[]
  |h::t-> if n=h then remove_from_list n t
    else h::remove_from_list n t;;` But i don't achieve do it with .filter, i think is something like...`let a num list = List.filter((fun x y-> not(List.exists x y)) num) list;;?`

Comment: Why do you think it's something like that? Have you looked at the type of `List.filter`?

Comment: @glennsl Of course...I know i need something of : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list, but I'm having trouble knowing how to take the item from the list...

Comment: Well just filter everything that's not equal to the item you want removed.

Comment: @Black_Dmn That's what `List.filter` does. You give `List.filter` a function and a list. Then `List.filter` calls you function with each item in the list. If your function returns true for a given item it is kept, otherwise it is dropped.

Comment: i.e. (fun x -> x <>5)

Answer (score 1):

Finally done, I had trouble understanding how to compare with the item I wanted to delete and how List.filter really works, but I already have just what I needed ...

`let remove_from_list elem list = List.filter(fun x-> x <> elem) list;;`

*Thanks to @glennsl and @G4143 for the help!*

Comment: Or taking advantage of currying:  `let remove_from_list elem lst = List.filter ((<>) elem) lst`